# Datanucleus 6 enhancer clone method causes infinite loop

Tags: java, inheritance, datanucleus

I use datanucleus 6 for the persistence of my java classes. A class extends a super class and overwrites the clone method. Both classes are persistable. The enhancer therefore creates a `dnClone` method and a `clone` method calling the `dnClone` method.

```
Object clone() {
    XXX copy = (XXX)dnClone();
    copy.dnFlags = (byte) 0;
    copy.dnStateManager = null;
    return copy;
}
```

The superclass' enhanced `clone` and `dnClone` methods looks like this:

```
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    MySuperClass copy = (MySuperClass)this.dnClone();
    copy.dnFlags = 0;
    copy.dnStateManager = null;
    return copy;
}

public Object dnClone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    MySuperClass dc = new MySuperClass(this.id);
    ....
    return dc;
}
```

The not enhanced `clone` method of the extending class looks like that:

```
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Object oCloned = super.clone();
    ExtClass edc = new ExtClass((MySuperClass)oCloned);
    edc.setFinishedBy(finishedBy);
    return edc;
}
```

The enhanced `clone` and `dnClone` method of the extending class look like this:

```
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    ExtClass copy = (ExtClass)this.dnClone();
    copy.dnFlags = 0;
    copy.dnStateManager = null;
    return copy;
}

public Object dnClone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Object oCloned = super.clone();
    ExtClass edc = new ExtClass((MySuperClass)oCloned);
    edc.setFinishedBy(this.finishedBy);
    return edc;
}
```

Calling the `super.clone()` method within the ExtClass' `clone` method therefore leads to the own `dnClone` method being called by the call of the `this.dnClone` method within the superclass' `clone` method.
This causes an infinite loop.

Is there an option that can be set for the enhancer for only creating a single `clone` method like it was created through datanucleus 5 enhancer?